# Can I apply an attribute like DebuggerHidden to skip over a function and all the function it calls?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

As stated in the question I have a static function (for logging) which I want to skip during debugging, so far I annotated it with the `DebuggerHidden` attribute, but for some reason Visual Studio 2010 will then jump into the calls inside this function which are not annotated with that attribute.

The thing is I have to press F11 a few times and I really don't to press F10 for these logging methods which I don't want to disable otherwise.

Comment: thanks @Abel, my darn german-english ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [DebuggerStepThrough] attribute is semantically closer to what you're trying to achieve.  But no, that doesn't fix it either.  I agree that it would be desirable but have no insight how hard this is to implement in the debugger.  Best place to find the guys that know this, and can actually fix it, is at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: hmm thanks, it shouldn't be that hard after all I can also press "Step Out" in the menu bar. But I can't see any attribute that does this.

Comment: There isn't one.  StepOut is bound to a *very* easy to reach key on my machine.

Comment: yeah of course ^^ but ive to run several big debugging runs and one if one press is wrong its just waste of time, on my keyboard the keys F-Keys are very small...

Comment: i mean if i press F10 where I should press F11 then i have to wait some minutes for the process to restart again, but i found the bug already :)

Comment: Well, "easy to reach" was the crux of my comment.  Start another question if you want to know how to change the key binding.

Comment: It's not even about easy reach, I think, and more about the non-undoable reflex of hitting the wrong button during a tedious debugging session.

Answer (score 3):

Add [`[DebuggerStepThrough]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx).

Comment: hmm its still doing it, btw I do have intellitrace on, if i use Conditional("Trace") maybe that works, will try in a sec

Comment: That will prevent the method from being called at all unless `TRACE` is defined in the calling assembly.